# HSQLDB Database multiple connections

Tags: hsqldb

Is it possible to connect to a HSQL database over multiple connections?

I have 2 connections using the same JDBC URL and the same hsqllib.jar and it appears I get a "new" database.

I imagine each connection is initializing the database in its memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to run HSQLDB in standalone mode, and then connect both instances of your application to the standalone instance. The [documentation](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/running-chapt.html#rgc_inprocess) describes how that start in server mode. For example, the following would start an in-memory database named `database1`:

```
java -cp ../lib/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.Server -database.0 mem:database1 -dbname.0 database1
```

You can then connect to that instance from your application using the following URL (assuming that everything is running on the same server):

```
jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/database1
```

Comment: can you please mention source reference of above statement, i want to dig more on this

Comment: I've linked to the the HSQLDB documention in my answer.